# Why does this background image not show in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image

(Yes I know another question about that obsolete browser)

My background image does not show in IE but works fine for Chrome and FF.

```
#wlt-DealView .blueBox .buyButton {
    background: url(http://domain.com/themes/regular/images/buybutton.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    font-size: 200%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin: 25px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Does anyone else want to have a go at editing the question?

Comment: I don't think IE is obsolete...

Comment: Of course it isn't. That's why I took out that line -- it seemed totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the wrong order on your `background` style.

```
background: transparent url(http://domain.com/themes/regular/images/buybutton.png) scroll  no-repeat 0 0;
```

Have the color at first and attachment as 3rd.

Comment: This is why shorthand stinks. I always recommend using the long versions (`background-image`, `background-position`....) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with images not displaying in older browsers becasuse the file had not saved properly.

so i'd suggest try saving your image again